# How to print an array wrapped in line instead of column?

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.6

in Python 3.6 I have a numpy array that is very long so the cmd print it like this:

```
Parameter W at iterations 1900: [[ 0.00942275]
[-0.02582744]
[-0.01197306]
...,
[-0.01123748]
[-0.02890738]
[ 0.02309689]]
```

I'm fine with wrapping all the values cause I don't really want to see them all, but I prefer them wrapped in a line like this:

```
[[-0.01197306] ...,[-0.01123748]]
```

Otherwise those values in column are moving the others print and I don't want this.

Comment: If it's a single column couldn't you just print the transpose? i.e. print(W.T)

Comment: Well that worked, my fault not thinking about it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure of the shape of the array (i.e. a column vector: `(n,1)`), why not define a simple function to pretty-print for you:

```
def shortprint(arr):
...:     print('[[{}] ..., [{}]]'.format(arr[0,0], arr[-1,0,]))

shortprint(arr)
[[-0.4759080597810965] ..., [-0.4759080597810965]]
```